# function is getting called repeatedly in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, func

By default I want any buttons with a class '.options' to perform the same actions which is to alert('Hello World'). IF you look below, you will see another button with an id name called 'append_another_content'. It's job is to append another `<input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">` and make it perform the same action as the rest of '.options' buttons. But the button that has just been appended will not perform any action unless I call myFunction() AGAIN, now  the problem is once I call myFunction() again once the new content has been appended, the previous buttons with a class '.options' will call myFunction() repeatedly depending on how many times you pressed the 'Append' button. My goal is, to only call the myFunction() once per each time '.options' button is clicked.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">
            <input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">
            <input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">
            <input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="append_another_content" value="Append"/>
    </body>

    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            $('.options').click(function(){
               alert('Hello Friends!');
            });
        }

        //By default I want any buttons with a class '.options' to perform the same actions which is to alert('Hello World')
        myFunction();

        $('#append_another_content').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/get_another_button.php',
            }).done(function(data){
                $('#wrap').append(data);
                //The data will just return '<input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">'

                //The button that has just been appended will not perform any action unless I call myFunction()
                myFunction();
            });

        }); 


    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the new element has no bound handlers, only the existing ones (the ones on the DOM before you called myFunction). Calling `myFunction` again adds yet another handler, and so on.

Consider using delegation instead, where an existing ancestor holds the handler for the existing and future descendants. The nearer the ancestor, the better. That way, you call `myFunction` *only once*.

[In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LWJ3S/), the ancestor `#wrap` holds the handlers for `.options`. This will take effect for all existing and future `.options`.

### HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <input type="button" class="options" value="Option">
    <input type="button" class="options" value="Option">
    <input type="button" class="options" value="Option">
    <input type="button" class="options" value="Option">
</div>
<input type="button" id="append_another_content" value="Append" />
```

### JS:

```
$('#wrap').on('click', '.options', function () {
  alert('Hello Friends!');
});

$('#append_another_content').click(function () {
  $(this)
    .siblings('#wrap')
    .append('<input type="button" class="options" value="Option">');
});
```

Comment: Nope, I get the same results. Once I clicked the 'Append' button. When you start clicking the previous buttton with a class name 'options', they start alerting the same function twice.

Comment: @ILikebanana I placed a demo with the answer.

Comment: I forgot to add, but what if the appended data came from the ajax returned. I edited my question above.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the event handler to the newly created element, you also add another event handler to all the previous elements.

You can add the event handler to only the element that you created:

```
function myFunction(e){
    $(e).click(function(){
       alert('Hello Friends!');
    });
}

myFunction('.options');

$('#append_another_content').click(function(){
    var input = $('<input type="button" class=".options" value="Option">');
    $(this).siblings('#wrap').append(input);
    myFunction(input);
});
```

#### Edit:

With the data from the AJAX call you can do exactly the same:

```
var input = $(data);
$('#wrap').append(input);
myFunction(input);
```

Comment: I forgot to add, but what if the appended data came from the ajax returned. I edited my question above.

Comment: @ILikebanana: You can do it the same way. I added an example above.

Comment: Nope you can't do it the same way, since the $.ajax({}).done(function(){//Can't reach myFunction})

Comment: @ILikebanana: Your function is global, it can be reached from anywhere in the code.

Comment: You are right, but the function is still been triggered multiple times once the new content has been appended. The last content works perfectly fine, it only trigger the function once. but the rest '.options' triggered the myFunction more than once.

Comment: @ILikebanana: Have you use the parameter to the function as I showed? Here is a demo showing that each button only have one event handler even after adding more buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/nd65a/

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the `.` in your HTML `class` attribute.  As it stands, `$(".options")` selects nothing because there is no element with `class="options"`.  It should be

```
<input type="button" class="options" value="Option" />
```

Next, either add the click handler to the button when you create it:

```
$(/*...*/).appendTo($(this).siblings("#wrap")).click(handler);
```

or use delegation:

```
$("#wrap").on("click", ".options", handler);
```